# How to pass Class Type Array into SQL server database using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Am working in VS2015 MVC project with Enterprise Library(Version=6.0.0.0). I need to send class type array as parameter to SQL stored procedure.

```
public static Database CoreDB
    {
        get
        {
            return _coreDatabase;
        }
    }

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
        Database coreDB = factory.Create("DB_Name");
        _coreDatabase = coreDB;
    }
```

In the view model, I have created array of class abc, that contains collection of ID's to be inserted in database.

```
public class viewModelClass
{
  public abc[] Details { get; set; }
  public int param1 { get; set; }
  public int param2 { get; set; }
  public int param3 { get; set; }
}

public class abc
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

After POST, am passing the values from model to stored procedure(I have created a User defined Table Type in SQL server for processing this array parameter).

```
 public int CreateAdminUser(viewModelClass userInfo)
    {
        string insertUserSP = Resources.InsertUser;
        DbCommand cmd = CoreDB.GetStoredProcCommand(insertUserSP);
        CoreDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param1", DbType.Int32, userInfo.param1);
        CoreDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param2", DbType.Int32, userInfo.param2);
        CoreDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param3", DbType.Int32, userInfo.param3);

        SqlParameter temp = new SqlParameter("@details", userInfo.Details);
        temp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        temp.TypeName = "dbo.UserDefinedTypeName";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(temp);

        int result = Convert.ToInt32(CoreDB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd));
        return result;
    }
```

Getting exception as "Failed to convert parameter value from a abc[] to IEnumerable'1" and inner exception as "Object must implement IConvertible" while executing ExecuteNonQuery().

My Issue is to pass this UserInfo.Details array as parameter to sql server.

This is my table type...

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserDefinedTypeName] AS TABLE( 
  [Id] [int] NOT NULL, 
  [Name] [varchar](200) NULL, 
  [IsActive] [bit] NULL )
```

Comment: You missed the type of `userInfo.param1`-`userInfo.param3`. Also `userInfo.abc` does not exist (I guess you meant Details). What is the signature of that stored procedure?

Comment: Actually,  public class viewModelClass
{
  public abc[] Details { get; set; }
  public int param1 { get; set; }
  public string param2 { get; set; }
  public int param3 { get; set; }
}  and SqlParameter temp = new SqlParameter("@details", userInfo.Details); My Issue is to pass this UserInfo.Details array as parameter to sql server

Comment: This is my table type...                                                                     CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserDefinedTypeName] AS TABLE(
 [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](200) NULL,
 [IsActive] [bit] NULL
)

Comment: In the future, please edit your post instead of adding code and info in comments (you can leave a comment that you updated it). Code is hard to read in comments and info may be lost. I already added your comments to the post for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass an array of class objects to a parameter of table type. You need to create a dataTable and populate it with the data which you want to pass to the

Consider following.

```
public int CreateAdminUser(viewModelClass userInfo)
{
    //Creating table with the same structure as defined table type in SQL Server
    var table = new DataTable();
    var dataColumn = new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    dataColumn = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    dataColumn = new DataColumn("IsActive", typeof(bool));
    table.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    // Populating table from the userInfo.Details array
    foreach (var item in userInfo.Details)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();

        row["Id"] = item.ID;
        row["Name"] = item.Name;
        row["IsActive"] = item.IsActive;

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    string insertUserSP = Resources.InsertUser;
    DbCommand cmd = CoreDB.GetStoredProcCommand(insertUserSP);
    CoreDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param1", DbType.Int32, userInfo.param1);
    CoreDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param2", DbType.Int32, userInfo.param2);
    CoreDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param3", DbType.Int32, userInfo.param3);

    SqlParameter temp = new SqlParameter("@details", SqlDbType.Structured);
    temp.TypeName = "dbo.UserDefinedTypeName";
    temp.Value = table;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(temp);

    int result = Convert.ToInt32(CoreDB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd));
    return result;
}
```

This should resolve your issue.